# Some errors in Xamarin after changing the Assembly Name and Icon

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm learning Xamarin e I've created an app that calculates Bhaskara(Cross-Platform). It works perfectly, but when I decide to change the app name [by changing the Assembly Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AksxD.png) and the Icon, [I get these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObsNq.png).

I don't use any Git, so I'll just paste here my code:

MainPage.xaml:

```
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
         <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:firstProject"
         x:Class="firstProject.MainPage">

<StackLayout Margin="10,10,10,0">
    <Label Text="Insira o valor 'a':"
           FontFamily="Century Gothic"
           FontSize="17"
           TranslationY="40"
           TranslationX="4"/>

    <Entry x:Name="aEntry"
           Keyboard="Numeric"
           TranslationX="0"
           TranslationY="25"
           />

    <Label Text="Insira o valor 'b':"      
           FontFamily="Century Gothic"
           FontSize="17"
           TranslationY="40"
           TranslationX="4"/>

    <Entry x:Name="bEntry"
           Keyboard="Numeric"
           TranslationX="0"
           TranslationY="25"/>

    <Label Text="Insira o valor 'c':"            
           FontFamily="Century Gothic"
           FontSize="17"
           TranslationY="40"
           TranslationX="4"/>

    <Entry x:Name="cEntry"
           Keyboard="Numeric"
           TranslationX="0"
           TranslationY="25"/>

    <Button x:Name="btnCalcular"
            Text="Calcular"
            FontFamily="Century Gothic"
            FontSize="17"
            TranslationY="50"
            Clicked="btnCalcular_Clicked"/>

</StackLayout>
```

`

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace firstProject
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {        
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Limpador()
        {
            aEntry.Text = "";
            bEntry.Text = "";
            cEntry.Text = "";

            aEntry.Focus();
        }

        private void btnCalcular_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double a, b, c, delta, res1, res2;

            a = Convert.ToDouble(aEntry.Text);
            if (aEntry.Text == "0")
            {
                DisplayAlert("Oops!", "Eita! 'a' não pode ser igual a 0!", "Ah, ta...");
                Limpador();
            }
            else
            {
                b = Convert.ToDouble(bEntry.Text);
                c = Convert.ToDouble(cEntry.Text);

                delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;

                if (delta < 0)
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Oops!", "Delta é menor que 0, não há raiz no conjunto dos reais", "Okay");
                    Limpador();
                }
                else
                {
                    res1 = (-(b) + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
                    res2 = (-(b) - Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);

                    DisplayAlert("Resultados", "As raízes são: " + res1 + " e " + res2, "Legal!");

                    Limpador();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't touched any other "activity", only wrote the code above. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before.

What I did to fix it:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete the `bin` and `obj` folders
3. Reopen solution and build

That usually fixed this sort of error for myself.